# Use environment variable to get another environment variable

Tags: kotlin

I am trying to get an env variable in Kotlin using another environment variable. For example, if I have a unique variable per AWS Region, I'd like something like this: `System.getenv("Key"-$aws_region")`. However, I can't seem to get it working right now (it is always null). Is the following syntax correct or am I missing something?

```
val awsRegionProvider: String =
    when {
        System.getenv("aws_region") != null -> System.getenv("aws_region")
        else -> ""
    }
}

val uniqueKey: String =
        System.getenv("UniqueKey-$awsRegionProvider")
```

I've already added aws_region & UniqueKey-us-west-2 to my env variables but uniqueKey complains about being null. Let me know if there are further details I can add.

Comment: What is `Provider`?  (Also, you can replace the whole `when` block with `System.getenv("aws_region") ?: ""`.)

Comment: Sorry I've removed the Provider part, wasn't necessary. Got it, I'll use that syntax instead then. Any ideas on the using a var for getting an env var?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try with overriding the getters as following:

```
val awsRegionProvider: String get() = System.getenv("aws_region")?: ""
 

val uniqueKey: String get() = System.getenv("UniqueKey-$awsRegionProvider")
```

Comment: Tried this out but still getting `System.getenv("UniqueK…y-$awsRegionProvider") must not be null`. I know aws_region and UniqueKey-us-west-2 both exist and that aws_region points to us-west-2...not sure what's the issue.

Comment: Looks like something is wrong with my env variables in Teamcity actually, since you were the only comment I've gone ahead and accepted your solution. Thanks for the help!